# Chained Converting Constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

```
class A{
public:
    A(int i){}
};
class B{
public:
    B(A){}
};
void test(B){};
int main() {
    A a=1;
    B b1=a;
    test(1);
}
```

I have two classes, where the first class has a converting int Ctor, which means that I can construct it by "assigning" an integer (first line).

The second class has a converting Ctor with argument type A. It is possible to construct b1 with  a (second line).

Is there any possibility to use multiple converting ctor in a chain, in such a way that the third row will compile?

Comment: A constructor is not the same as assigment. You should define both.

Comment: I know that assignment and Ctors are different things, but my problem ony refers to Ctors, or? I agree that I should have assignment operators, but they would not held in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *explicitly* construct `B` from `int`, but not *implicitly*:

```
test(B{1});  // ok
test(1);     // Not ok
```

That being said, this half-way measure also works:

```
test({1});  // ok
```

And everything above works for only *one* implicitly generated middle class (`A`).  Such a chain can not be further extended.